# Remove string after the hyphen

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have multiple strings written at the same way:

- **Name**-372198
- **Another**-9849204
- **Something**-3439483

I want to split the string into two parts: first one before the hyphen and the other after the hyphen.

I'm stuck with Objective-c Regular Expression!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're using a regular expression. What's wrong with:

```
NSString *theString = @"Name-372198";
NSArray *stringComponents = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

The `stringComponents` array will hold: `{ @"Name", @"372198" }`

Code not tested but should work.

Comment: I was looking for this kind of methods and didn't find. But it seems like there's one! And it works!. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is only one `-` you might want to look at

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:options:

Answer (score 0):

No need of a regular expression in this case. 
This would do fine

```
NSArray *stringParts=[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

NSString *part1=stringParts[0]; 
// has the part before the hyphen
NSString *part2=stringParts[1];
// has the part after the hyphen
```